PHP 7.4 is ignoring incorrect parameter passing
I have the following class with the following constructor:
class Film {
    private string $name; 
    private int $releaseYear;
    private string $genre;
    private array $notes = [];

    public function __construct(string $name, int $releaseYear, string $genre)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->releaseYear = $releaseYear;
        $this->genre = $genre;
        $this->notes = [];
    }
}

My source code contains the following command:
$film = new Film(
    'Thor - Ragnarok',
    2021,
    'Superhero',
    180
);

I am passing a fourth parameter that is not in the constructor, but the code runs normally.
I was expecting the code to produce an error and not allow me to pass an extra parameter to the constructor.
I tried adding the following lines to the code, but the code still runs:
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
Is this normal? Shouldn't PHP have an error handling mechanism for such cases?

Note you don't need $this->notes = []; in the constructor because you've already set a default in the definition.

You can use PHPStan to detect this, if desired.

hmm, interesting. its working
